# How to use a MCT Trigger II external USB2DVIE3 adaptor?

Tags: drivers, usb, external-monitor, dvi

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - relative newbie.

Would really like to know if I can use the Startech USB2DVIE3 adapter.  I've done some reading but haven't got very far.  It uses DisplayLink technology (I think) but with a different chipset (MCT T2-285B) to other devices.

There's a suggestion that this later device will be supported in the kernel 3.5 however I'd really like to hear from anyone who has had success getting this working.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking into the USB2VGAE3 myself (which is based on the T2-285A), and am willing to write the driver.... just trying to get MCT to talk to me atm.

Comment: any update to this? are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on 13.10

Comment: I've not retried this on anything later than 12.04 since the original post, but I'd be most interested if anyone else has had success since.